# Can I make many class for icon

Tags: css, html5-canvas, icons, favicon

I have a problem , I would like to change just color of one icon but I can't put other class because icon font-awasome have a class.
I put em but it's not work. I want change last icon (color).
Can you help me ?

```
<div class="text">
              <h4>Los Angeles</h4>
              <p class="price">Nuit à partir de <strong>25€</strong></p>CC
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you just need to target the last child which is the last icon, `.fas.fa-star:last-child { color: }`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you cannot add another CSS class, I don't see any reason not to do that.

But anyways other options are:

using an inline style tag:

```
<i class="fas fa-star" style="color: red;"></i>
```

or if you know the position, you know it's always the third element, you can use `:nth-child()`.
This example will change the color of the third icon

```
.text i:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
.text .fas.fa-star {
  color: black;
}

.text .fas.fa-star:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <span class="fas fa-star">1</span>
  <span class="fas fa-star">2</span>
  <span class="fas fa-star">3</span>
  <span class="fas fa-star">4</span>
  <span class="fas fa-star">5</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried but the problem is that I have a section with articles that contain the same composition and I want select icon with css3.

Yes, It works great for styling directly on html thank you.
I will like to do all my styles only in the css part.
First article exemple I want to select 2last icon, dans secondly article just last icon I can put div with class ?

```
  <article>
          <a href="#">
            <div>
              <img
                class="image"
                src="Public/Images/hebergements/4_small/HotelLesmouettes.jpg"
                alt="Hôtel les mouettes"
              />
             
            </div>

            <div class="text">
              <h4>Hôtel Les mouettes</h4>
              <p class="price">Nuit à partir de 76<strong>€</strong></p>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            </div>
          </a>
        </article>
      </div>
     

      <div class="Lodging-article">
        <article>
          <a href="#"
            >
            <div>
              <img
                class="image"
                src="Public/Images/hebergements/4_small/Hoteldelamer.jpg"
                alt="Hôtel de la mer"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="text">
              <h4>Hôtel de la mer</h4>
              <p class="price">Nuit à partir de 46<strong>€</strong></p>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
             <i class="fas fa-star" ></i>
            </div>
          
          </a>
        </article>
```